# MYSQL Three Items then div Followed By Three items then Div

Tags: php, mysql

I've  been searching previous posts, but havent been able to find what I'm looking for. Possibly because I don't know how to phrase it or what the term would be to find it. What this script does is simply grab articles from database and list them out. Simple enough, right. No issues there, but I wanted to insert a div for advertisments for example every 3-4 entries listed. So it would be post#1, post#2, post#3, AD here,post#4,post#5,post#6,Another Ad Here, ect. Is there a way to do that and what would this be called for further search help?

```
        $blogList = '';
        include "connect.php"; 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id >8 LIMIT 6"); 
        $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
        if ($productCount > 0) {
            // get all the product details
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
                $id = $row["id"];
                $article_title = $row["article_title"];
                $category = $row["category"];
                $readmore = $row["readmore"];   
                $author = $row["author"];
                $date_added = $row["date_added"];
                $content = $row["content"];
                $short = substr(strip_tags($content), 0, 750);
                $shortTitle = substr(strip_tags($article_title), 0, 45);
                $blogList .= '  <div class="blogSnippetTitle"><a href="http://www.#.com/better-trader.php?id='.$id.'"><h2>'.$article_title.'</h2></a></div><div class="blogSnippet"><div class="blogImage"><img src="http://www.#.com/trading_images/'.$id.'.jpg" height="142px" width="200px" alt="'.$category.' '.$shortTitle.'" /></div><div class="blogSnippetPrev"><div class="citation">By <span style="color:#006699;">'.$author.'</span> on <span style="color:#99aacc;">'.$date_added.'</span> in <span style="color:#006699;">'.$category.'</span></div>
                <div class="snippet">'.$short.'...<br /></div>
                <div class="readMoreButton"><br /><a href="http://www.#.com/better-trader.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="http://www.#.com/images/read_more.png" alt="read more graphic" /></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
             }

        }else {
        $blogList = "You have no products listed in your store yet";
        }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Sergio this is the upadted code.

```
<?php 
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    $blogList = '';
    include "connect.php"; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id >8 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6"); 
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
        $counter = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
            $id = $row["id"];
            $article_title = $row["article_title"];
            $category = $row["category"];
            $readmore = $row["readmore"];   
            $author = $row["author"];
            $date_added = $row["date_added"];
            $content = $row["content"];
            $short = substr(strip_tags($content), 0, 750);
            $shortTitle = substr(strip_tags($article_title), 0, 45);
            $counter++;
            if ($counter == 4){ $blogList .= '<div class="blogSnippetTitle"><a href="http://www.#.com/better-trader.php?id='.$id.'"><h2>'.$article_title.'</h2></a></div><div class="blogSnippet"><div class="blogImage"><img src="http://www.#.com/trading_images/'.$id.'.jpg" height="142px" width="200px" alt="'.$category.' '.$shortTitle.'" /></div><div class="blogSnippetPrev"><div class="citation">By <span style="color:#006699;">'.$author.'</span> on <span style="color:#99aacc;">'.$date_added.'</span> in <span style="color:#006699;">'.$category.'</span></div>
            <div class="snippet">'.$short.'...<br /></div>
            <div class="readMoreButton"><br /><a href="http://www.#.com/better-trader.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="http://www.#.com/images/read_more.png" alt="read more graphic" /></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>' test; $counter = 0; }


    }else {
    $blogList = "You have no products listed in your store yet";
    }
mysql_close();
?>
```

I'm not sure what AD means Sergio. If this isn't what you meant please let me know.

Comment: your `mysql_query` is deprecated, please read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: Sergio, I'm not able to figure out the order of things. I keep getting many errors. I've been able to reference other stackoverflow posts with your description, but can't seem to get it right. Any tips?

Comment: What errors do you get, exactly?

Comment: It will be of NO USE to give `HELP` or Suggestion for someone to stay safe in a Building that is marked to be demolished in few minutes... **PLEASE HEAR THIS:** Your `mysql_query` is like a building marked `X`... It's is 'deprecated'.. No support is gonna be provided in good faith when you stick to it... Go for `PDO` or other `prepared statement` methods to get up_to_date Help and Support.

Comment: @ErickBest his problem has (most probably) got nothing to do with PDO.

Comment: I think I found your problem, one thing we all missed. 1 sec and I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a counter inside your loop.
For example:

```
$counter = 0; // before the loop starts
```

and inside the loop:

```
$counter++;
if ($counter == 4){ $blogList .= "/* your AD here*/" ; $counter = 0; }
```

Hope this helps
(and remember your mysql_query is deprecated, read more about it **[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)**)

**EDIT:**

```
    <?php 
    // Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
    // Connect to the MySQL database  

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);  //this is for debugging, remove if you dont need anymore
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);       //this is for debugging, remove if you dont need anymore

    $blogList = '';
    include "connect.php"; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id >8 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6"); 
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
        $counter = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($productCount)){ 
            $id = $row["id"];
            $article_title = $row["article_title"];
            $category = $row["category"];
            $readmore = $row["readmore"];   
            $author = $row["author"];
            $date_added = $row["date_added"];
            $content = $row["content"];
            $short = substr(strip_tags($content), 0, 750);
            $shortTitle = substr(strip_tags($article_title), 0, 45);
            $counter++;
            if ($counter == 4){ $blogList .= '<div class="blogSnippetTitle"><a href="http://www.#.com/better-trader.php?id='.$id.'"><h2>'.$article_title.'</h2></a></div><div class="blogSnippet"><div class="blogImage"><img src="http://www.#.com/trading_images/'.$id.'.jpg" height="142px" width="200px" alt="'.$category.' '.$shortTitle.'" /></div><div class="blogSnippetPrev"><div class="citation">By <span style="color:#006699;">'.$author.'</span> on <span style="color:#99aacc;">'.$date_added.'</span> in <span style="color:#006699;">'.$category.'</span></div>
            <div class="snippet">'.$short.'...<br /></div>
            <div class="readMoreButton"><br /><a href="http://www.#.com/better-trader.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="http://www.#.com/images/read_more.png" alt="read more graphic" /></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>'; 
    $counter = 0;}
$blogList .= '  <div class="blogSnippetTitle"><a href="http://www.#.com/better-trader.php?id='.$id.'"><h2>'.$article_title.'</h2></a></div><div class="blogSnippet"><div class="blogImage"><img src="http://www.#.com/trading_images/'.$id.'.jpg" height="142px" width="200px" alt="'.$category.' '.$shortTitle.'" /></div><div class="blogSnippetPrev"><div class="citation">By <span style="color:#006699;">'.$author.'</span> on <span style="color:#99aacc;">'.$date_added.'</span> in <span style="color:#006699;">'.$category.'</span></div>
            <div class="snippet">'.$short.'...<br /></div>
            <div class="readMoreButton"><br /><a href="http://www.#.com/better-trader.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="http://www.#.com/images/read_more.png" alt="read more graphic" /></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
'; 
        }
    }
    else {
        $blogList = "You have no products listed in your store yet";
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Sergio I couldn't get this to work...I'm trying to figure out how it all goes together with my current code. I've tried many different things, but havn't done it just yet. How are you suggestion this be implemented within what I have? I got many different errors, but most common t_v

Comment: Sergio I'm not sure what AD is, but I've added what I did last above.

Comment: What is `test;` just in the end of the while loop?

Comment: thats where you ad mentioned your ad here. I saw that and didnt think I was reading that right.

Comment: (leave the `;`, remove just the "test" word)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE is the error that I'm receiving.

Comment: Add one more `}` before `mysql_close();` to close the while loop.

Comment: Okay, no longer getting the error after adjustments, but no output anymore. I also don't understand really what is happening here. Do I leave the other $blogList in tact then in the new blogList use something else? Can I have both there? I don't understand where the other content would be placed for output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32284/discussion-between-sergio-and-hire-logo)

Comment: @HireLogo, just updated my answer. Besides some `{}` closing problems you had `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($productCount)){` wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the modulo operator (called % or MOD).

Modulo yields the remainder of an integer division. So 3 MOD 3 = 0, 5 MOD 2 = 1, 10 MOD 3 = 1 etc. ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation ).

Use as in the previois answer with a loop variable

```
$loopcount = 0;

while(...) {
  if ($loopcount MOD 3 == 0) {
    // do this every 3rd loop iteration
  }
  $loopcount++;
}
```

This way you don't have to reset the loop counter.